# What does terminating I2C bus mean

Tags: i2c, digital-communications

I am designing a PCB which has a micro and some chips that work with I2C.

I have used pull-ups (4.7 kOhm) to VCC (3.3V in my case) on the lines. Just like the picture below. I added 150 Ohm resistors myself...I have no idea if they are necessary or not but I have heard a low value series resistance can help with reducing noise??

Regarding termination, I have read official documentation [Every I2C bus must be terminated](http://www.i2c-bus.org/termination/). The problem is, there are no schematic/photo on that page and I can not understand what they mean in that page.

My naive understanding of termination is that the bus should be end-up with some resistors, something like:

[image]

So, what should I do?

1. Keep the series resistors?
2. Add termination resistors at the end? if so to ground or VCC and what values?

Comment: When that ''official' documentation refers to 'termination', it's referring to those pullup resistors - nothing more.
Your idea of termination is more applicable to a balanced/differential comms bus like RS-485.
Unless you have a good reason for those 150R resistors and know what you're doing with them, get rid of them too - they're just going to cause you headaches with 'soft mushy' low bits.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for feedback...about the series resistors...what about a very low value like 10 Ohm? or you mean no series resistor at all?

Comment: @DEKKER - "*I have read official documentation  [...]*" FYI, that link you gave is **not** the *official* I2C documentation. That site is run by a commercial company who sell, among other things, I2C-related test equipment. Notice that the word "termination" does not appear in the [I2C specification](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf). "*I can not understand what they mean in that page.*" I'm not surprised - I think it could be confusing to someone who didn't already know I2C and its electrical behaviour. :-(

Comment: Those series resistors will make the low bits from your master nt as low as they could be, which might cause trouble for you. They'll also reduce the slew rate of transitions on the bus, and will therefor reduce the maximum bus speed you can work at, while also possibly reducing generated EMI. But unless you have a particular EMI issue you're trying to solve then leave them out (or populate them as 0R jumpers).

Comment: @SamGibson Damn I have been fooled by that website then!

Comment: @brhans Sure I will leave the resistors as 0R jumpers just in case! Thanks for the info I think I understand their attribute to the I2C now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The termination resistors in the case of I2C are just the pullup resistors. You don't need terminators in the normal transmission line meaning of the word, because the bus is very short compared to the operating bandwidth so reflections are not an issue.

Further leaving in the series resistors will reduce the ability of the bus master to pull the bus lines close to ground. This will reduce noise margin, degrading performance. Leave them out and use the 4k7 pullup resistors only. Also note that I2C specifies a maximum rise time so the exact pullup resistor value you require will depend on the total bus capacitance.